# Clean architecture login flow

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I am developing a login screen in my Android application with a clean architecture.

When using the login in successfully, I need to save the token to shared preferences.

And on the splash screen, I need to check whether a user is logged in or not

So my question is that where is the perfect place:

1. To save token

should I save token in LoginUseCase (domain layer)

```
class LoginUseCase(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) {

    fun execute(username: String, password: String): Single<Token> {
        return userRepository.login(username, password)
            .andThen(userRepository.saveToken(.....)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.getIOScheduler())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.getUIScheduler())
    }

}
```

Or should I make save token as an UseCase and save the token in presenter layer

```
class LoginPresenter(private val view: LoginContract.View,
                     private val setLoginStateUseCase: SetLoginStateUseCase,
                     private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase,
                     private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider): LoginContract.Presenter {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun performLogin(username: String, password: String) {

        if (username.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            view.onShowLoginError("Field should not be empty")
        } else {
            view.showLoading()
            val disposable = loginUseCase.execute(username, password)
                    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.getIOScheduler())
                    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.getUIScheduler())
                    .andThen(setLoginStateUseCase.execute())
                    .subscribe({
                        view.hideLoading()
                        view.onLoginSuccess()
                    }, {error ->
                        view.hideLoading()
                        view.onShowLoginError(error.localizedMessage)
                    })
            compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
        }
    }
```

The same question with check user is logged in or not. Should I make that action a use-case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion it makes pretty much sense to perform that operation in the domain layer use case. Imagine you have another different module in the same project for a TV app. It's likely that the `LoginPresenter` may differ from the mobile app module's one, however, you could be able to reuse the very same use case. Thus, you don't have to be aware on each `LoginPresenter` variation you implement to save the token once the use case is executed.

On the other hand, I'd suggest to take a look at how the folks of Google face the login process using a delegate pattern in [their Google I/O application](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/signin/SignInViewModelDelegate.kt). It's a very common pattern to use a `currentUser` observable along your application giving you plenty of advantages. For example, although I wouldn't label it as a pure clean architecture reference project, the guys of kickstarter developed an interesting `MVVM+RxJava` architecture using the [currentUser](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/blob/v1.8.1/app/src/main/java/com/kickstarter/libs/CurrentUser.java) paradigm I've talked about which deserves to have a glance also.